# Point table to another table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, meta-method

is there any way to point table to another table? for example:

```
local a = {}
local b = {}
a.name = "Josh"
print(a.name) -- Prints 'Josh'
print(b.name) -- Prints 'Josh' aswell
a.name = "I don't have a name"
print(a.name) -- Print 'I don't have a name'
print(b.name) -- Prints 'I don't have a name' aswell
```

I hope you get my point.. thanks

EDIT:

Okay, so here is the idea:

I am making a dinamic function that is like this

```
local table = { 1, 2, "hey" }

function drawimage(name, posx, posy referencetable)
    _tabledata[name] = { posx = posx, posy = posy, reference = {}}
    setmetatable(_tabledata[name].reference, { __index = referencetable })
end

drawimage("Header", 0, 50, table)
```

All good and fine, values work and we are all happy.. the problem occurs when the reference table changes it's value in this way

```
local data = { 123123, 545454, "heyou" } -- Data is sent from another script via a trigger
table = data
```

Since I am not updating it by an index (ie: table[1] = 9999) reference variable is 'unsynced' with the real one, I hope you understand :)

EDIT2:

Okay here is a self working example of my main problem

```
local maintable = { "Stack", "Overflow" }
local maintablecopy = {}

maintablecopy = maintable

print("maintable[1] = " ..maintable[1]) -- Prints Stack
print("maintable[2] = " ..maintable[2]) -- Prints Overflow
print("")
print("maintablecopy[1] = " ..maintablecopy[1]) -- Prints Stack
print("maintablecopy[2] = " ..maintablecopy[2]) -- Prints Overflow
print("")

print("Changing values..")
local newdata = { "Hello", "World" }
maintable = newdata

print("")
print("maintable[1] = " ..maintable[1]) -- Prints Hello
print("maintable[2] = " ..maintable[2]) -- Prints World
print("")
print("maintablecopy[1] = " ..maintablecopy[1]) -- Prints Stack    -- PROBLEM
print("maintablecopy[2] = " ..maintablecopy[2]) -- Prints Overflow -- PROBLEM

print("Using setmetatable..")

maintable = { "Stack", "Overflow" }
maintablecopy = {}
setmetatable(maintablecopy, { __index = maintable })

print("maintable[1] = " ..maintable[1]) -- Prints Stack
print("maintable[2] = " ..maintable[2]) -- Prints Overflow
print("")
print("maintablecopy[1] = " ..maintablecopy[1]) -- Prints Stack
print("maintablecopy[2] = " ..maintablecopy[2]) -- Prints Overflow
print("")

print("Changing values..")
local newdata = { "Hello", "World" }
maintable = newdata

print("")
print("maintable[1] = " ..maintable[1]) -- Prints Hello
print("maintable[2] = " ..maintable[2]) -- Prints World
print("")
print("maintablecopy[1] = " ..maintablecopy[1]) -- Prints Stack    -- PROBLEM
print("maintablecopy[2] = " ..maintablecopy[2]) -- Prints Overflow -- PROBLEM
```

Why I cannot directly point it to the table when the variable updates? becouse I have 20 tables to update, it would be easier to do this

```
local _dynamics = {}

local tbl1 = { "Hey", 8787 } 
local tbl2 = { 123, "There" }
local tbl3 = { "You", 1111 }  

function dynamicFunction(name, posx, posy, textsize, reference)
    _dynamics[name] = { posx = posx, posy = posy, textsize = textsize, reference = reference }
end

dynamicFunction("first", 0, 0, 5, tbl1)
dynamicFunction("second", 0, 0, 5, tbl2)
dynamicFunction("third", 0, 0, 5, tbl3)

for key in pairs(_dynamics) do
    local inf = _dynamics[key]
    for i = 1, #inf.reference do
        print(inf.reference[i])
        if i == #inf.reference then
            print("")
        end
    end
end

print("")
print("")

tbl1 = { "aaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbb" }
tbl2 = { "ccccccccccc", "ttttttttttt" }
tbl3 = { "rrrrrrr", "yyyyyyyyyyy" }

for key in pairs(_dynamics) do
    local inf = _dynamics[key]
    for i = 1, #inf.reference do
        print(inf.reference[i])
        if i == #inf.reference then
            print("")
        end
    end
end

print("Values should get updated on the reference variable, but it doesn't.. this would save me     to do a check for every single variable")
```

You can run it on http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lua_online.php to see yourself what I mean.

Sorry if it's a mess but my english is not the best :D

Comment: Why not just `b = a`?

Comment: Becouse b does not get updated if a changes.

Comment: @Feche1320 Yes, it would. The code `b=a` causes two variables to reference the exact same table in memory. All changes to one affect the "other", because they are the same. I think that you are confused about variables holding tables versus referencing tables. Perhaps you mean that if you do `a={t=1} b=a a={t=2}` then `b` is not "updated" to use the same table as `a` is re-pointed to reference?

Comment: Your edit is a good step in the right direction, but it is not sufficient. Please create a standalone demo showcasing your problem, with code that can be run on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`__index` metamethod](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html):

```
local a = { name="Josh" }
local b = {}

print(a.name) --> Josh
print(b.name) --> nil

setmetatable(b,{__index=a})
print(b.name) --> Josh

a.name = "Gilligan"
print(a.name) --> Gilligan
print(b.name) --> Gilligan

-- but note! the shadow
b.name = "overridden"
print(a.name) --> Gilligan
print(b.name) --> overridden

b.name = nil
print(a.name) --> Gilligan
print(b.name) --> Gilligan
```

For more details, I offer up this article of mine:
http://phrogz.net/lua/LearningLua_ValuesAndMetatables.html

---

**Response to Edit2**:

Let me summarize the problems with some of your code:

```
local maintablecopy = {}
maintablecopy = maintable
```

With the above code you create one table, set `maintablecopy` to reference that table, and then you completely abandon it when you set `maintablecopy` to instead reference a different table. This demonstrates a lack of understanding of how variables work.

```
local newdata = { "Hello", "World" }
maintable = newdata
```

Again, you are not "copying" `newdata` into `maintable`, you are changing the variable to reference the same table here.

```
maintable = { "Stack", "Overflow" }
maintablecopy = {}
setmetatable(maintablecopy, { __index = maintable })

-- …

local newdata = { "Hello", "World" }
maintable = newdata
```

Again, same problem. Here are some ways to change your code:

### Replace a Table's Contents

Instead of `maintable = newdata` you could do this:

```
function copytable(from,to_table)
  -- erase all old keys
  for k,_ in pairs(to_table) do to_table[k] = nil end

  -- copy the new ones over
  for k,v in pairs(from) do to_table[k] = v end
end

local a = { name="Foo" }
local b = {}
copytable(a,b)
print(a.name == b.name) --> true

local c = { name="NEW" }
copytable(c,b)
print(c.name == b.name) --> true
```

However, doing this will not cause `b` to update if `c` changes.

```
c.name = "EVEN NEWER"
print(c.name == b.name) --> false
```

### Update the __index

```
local a = { name="Foo" }
local b = setmetatable({},{__index=a})
print(a.name == b.name) --> true

-- cause b to follow c now instead of a
local c = { name="NEW" }
getmetatable(b).__index = c
print(c.name == b.name) --> true

c.name = "EVEN NEWER"
print(c.name == b.name) --> true
```

In general, you need to step back and describe the original problem you are trying to solve, instead of this [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help :)

I am having some issues tough, before asking I saw that article and did what you did, I found out that if I do this
    _mapcache = { 123, 123213}
    _test = {}
    setmetatable(_test, { __index = _mapcache })
    print(_test[1])
Does work, but if I do this:
    function callThisFunction()
        setmetatable(_test, { __index = _mapcache })
    end   
    _mapcache = { 123, 123213}
    _test = {}
    callThisFunction()
    print(_test[1])
Doesn't work for some reason.. I have to use setmetatable inside a function, that's why :P

Comment: Actually, I retract what I said before.. I encountered the problem.. 

I have table _mapcache and it get's updated with a trigger from another script, so when I update _mapcache I do _mapcache = data

There is the problem, if I change _mapcache directly (not by pointing out a specific index, example _mapcache.name = "Josh") metatable does not get updated

Comment: @Feche1320 It is hard to understand your problem from code placed in  comments. Please edit your question with updated details showing exactly your problem (in a minimal way that uses real code to actually reproduce it), or post a new question on the site with that full code. And please see my comment on your question, above.

Comment: I have added an update to my answer based on your new problem description.

Comment: Resolved, thank you all for your help and sorry for XY problem :p